# Partial is not being updated after ajax call in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

**in my action.js.erb file**

```
$("#performance").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'performance_table',questions: @questions, groups: @groups, performances: @performances) %>")
```

**in my view**

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <div id="performance">
   <%= render 'performance_table', :questions => @questions, :groups => @groups, :performances => @performances  %> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

in my controller_action

```
@groups = classroom.groups
@questions = @quiz.questions
@performances = Array.new
i = 0
group_ids.each do |g|
  question_ids.each do |q|
    @performances.push(Answer.where("group_id = ? AND question_id = ?",g,q).first.userans)
  end
end
```

I am making an ajax call to an action and then I in the file of action.js.erb I am updating the html of my div by rendering the same partial but with updated values but partial is not rendering updated values. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong . console is also showing no error at all

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an alert message before and after you call .html(). Do both alerts pop up? If so, that means the issue most likely isn't with your javascript.

Comment: alert is not working in performance.js.erb file, why is that? and yes server log shows reading controller#method as JSON, is that a problem??

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a problem request must be of type "js", please provide how you are making ajax call?
 that is the view part of it

Comment: $.ajax({
 url: "/quiz_performance",
 type: "POST",
 data: {quiz_id:<%= @quiz.id%>, question_ids:<%=question_ids%>,group_ids:<%= group_ids%>},
   dataType: "json",
complete: function() {},
 success: function() {
console.log('comnig here')
 $('.column').html("<h1>Why this shit</h1>")
         },
         error: function() {
          $('.column').html("<h1>Why this shit</h1>")
         }
       })

Comment: this is how i am making ajax call

Comment: Try changing your dataType to be 'script' instead of 'json'.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you replace the existing values of `<div id="performance"> </div>`. Try to append the new values by using append method in js.